# Compute and graph predicted values for all possible levels and values from a FE logit model’s predictors

Tags: r, marginal-effects, logits

I'm waiting for the [`bife`](https://github.com/amrei-stammann/bife/issues) (binary fixed effects) package to be supported in [`ggeffects`](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/issues/230) but in the meantime I'd 1st) like to figure out how I can replicate what ggeffects does, and (very 2nd) like to understand whether I should be using the Average Predicted Effect (APEs) or predicted probabilities.

In normal circumstances, I would run a `glm` and then plot the variable of interest using `ggeffects`.

```
testglm <- iris %>%
  mutate(LengthDummy = if_else(Sepal.Length > 5, "Long", "Short") %>% as_factor(.)) %>%
  glm(LengthDummy ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species, data = .,  family = binomial)
ggeffects::ggeffect(testglm, terms = "Petal.Length")
```

You should get this table:

```
# Predicted probabilities of LengthDummy
Petal.Length | Predicted |       95% CI
---------------------------------------
        1.00 |      1.00 | [0.41, 1.00]
        1.50 |      1.00 | [0.24, 1.00]
        2.50 |      0.58 | [0.04, 0.98]
        3.50 |      0.01 | [0.00, 0.09]
        4.00 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.03]
        4.50 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.01]
        5.50 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]
        7.00 |      0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]
```

This output, where Petal.Length is a range of (8) values in the dataset, and all the other model predictors are held at their mean, is produced and can be piped into `plot()` (`ggeffects::ggeffect(testglm, terms = "Petal.Length")%>% plot()`) or into `ggplot2()`.

```
ggeffects::ggeffect(testglm, terms = "Petal.Length") %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x, predicted))+ 
  geom_line()
```

This time, however, my model (not an iris project obviously, this is an example dataset) requires FE. So, my question is, how do I "compute predicted values for all possible levels and values from a logit model’s predictors" as `ggeffects` does for `bife` glm?

```
library(bife)
fetest <- iris%>% mutate(LengthDummy= if_else(Sepal.Length>5, "Long", "Short") %>% as_factor(.)) %>%  
                 bife(LengthDummy~ Sepal.Width+ Petal.Length+Petal.Width | Species, data = ., "logit")
```

I can obtain the Average Predicted Effects which gives me the average of each predictor's effects using `APEsIris <- summary(get_APEs(fetest))`. This of course produces a single average for Petal.Length, not 8. I can compute a dataframe with se and the CI, but it is not the equivalent (single estimates)

```
    object <- APEsIris
    estimate <- object[["delta"]]
    se <- sqrt(diag(object[["vcov"]]))
    z <- estimate/se
    p <- 2 * pnorm(-abs(z))
    conf.low <- estimate-1.96*se
    conf.high <- estimate+1.96*se
    term <- names(estimate)
    APEsdf <- data.frame(term, estimate, se, conf.low, conf.high, z, p)
    colnames(cm) <- c("term", "estimate", 
                      "std.error", "conf.low", "conf.high", "statistic", "p.value")
    #colnames(cm) <- c("term", "estimate", "Std. error", "Lower bound", "Upper bound", "statistic", "Pr(> |z|)")
    rownames(cm) <- NULL
    APEsdf <- as.data.frame(APEsdf)
```

So what about predicting?

`predictedbifes<-predict.bife(fetest)` produces 150 predictions, the number of observations, in the dataset. Even if I graph them, I don't understand how I would manipulate the predictions to vary along the observed values of Petal.Length holding all other predictors at the mean.

In short, how can I reproduce `ggeffects` calculations to produce a marginal effects table I can use to graph for different variables in the model of this fixed effect logit?